# AWS Cloud Watch Alarms -- Multiple Instances Per Alarm

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudwatch

Perhaps I'm misunderstanding how to use AWS Cloudwatch alarms but I don't seem to be able to add an alarm to multiple EC2 instances.  I created an alarm that would send a notification if CPUUtilization > 70 and added it to a single EC2 instance... which is great.  However, I needed to add a second EC2 node to the ELB and tried to add the created alarm to that instance as well and I can't figure out how to do it.  I'd rather not have to create another alarm measuring the exact same metric for every instance I create.   What am I missing?  Is there an easier way to do what I'm trying to do?

What I'm trying to do is create a 'EC2 CPU Utilization' alarm, and reuse this for all my EC2 instances I have deployed.

Comment: there is a similar post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21312838/aws-cloudwatch-alarms-to-multiple-ec2-instances

Answer (score 0):

You are correct, CloudWatch alarms can only be applied to individual CloudWatch metrics, which are usually associated with a specific instance. If you need to watch the same metric on many instances, you'll have to create the alarms along with the instances, or perhaps run an AWS Lambda script to register alarms when none are present.